# Why is my function not producing the desired result?

Tags: javascript

```
const character = {
  name: 'Simon',
  getCharacter() {
    return this.name;
  }
};

const giveMeTheCharacterNOW = character.getCharacter.bind(character);
console.log('?', giveMeTheCharacterNOW);
```

the answer should be like  "? simon"
// How do you fix this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a function.

Just call the function.

```js
const
    character = {
        name: 'Simon',
        getCharacter() {
            return this.name;
        }
    },
    giveMeTheCharacterNOW = character.getCharacter.bind(character);

console.log('?', giveMeTheCharacterNOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const character = {
  name: 'Simon',
  getCharacter() {
  return this.name;
  }
  };
  const giveMeTheCharacterNOW = character.getCharacter();
  console.log('?', giveMeTheCharacterNOW);
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers